# Filling a map with a query

Tags: apex, query, map, field-mapping

i'm having big troubles to fill a map with the data of **fields of related objects** to the one that is declared as value.

```
Map<Id,GPMIR_obj_energyLead__c> mapToMap = new Map<Id,GPMIR_obj_energyLead__c>([SELECT Id, 
    IdCommunity__c, 
    Community__c, 
    Community__r.name__c, 
    Community__r.installation__r.CUPSInmueble__r.StreetSP__c, 
    Community__r.partitionCoefficient__c
FROM GPMIR_obj_energyLead__c
WHERE Id IN : mapRelateLeadsWithCommunities.keySet() 
AND IdCommunity__c IN : mapRelateLeadsWithCommunities.values()]);
```

**Here we have three objects:**

1. GPMIR_obj_energyLead__c
2. SM_Community__c
3. SM_Installation__c
4. PointOfDelivery__c

Every one of them is the many in a many to one relationship with the next one in the list

When i debug the Map **i'm only getting the fields of GPMIR_obj_energyLead__c** (Id,IdCommunity__c,Community__c)

The query is right is SOQL, but there is something wrong in the development

Any idea of what am i doing wrong?

Comment: the system.debug line won't show the parent recs; you need to use a bit of apex to show the parent fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a "feature" of System.debug of an sobject

A way to verify:

```
String[] debugLines = new List<String>();
for (ID recId : mapToMap.keySet() ) {
  GPMIR_obj_energyLead__c rec = mapToMap.get(recId);
  debugLines.add(rec + ' ' + rec.Community__r.Name__c +  ' ' +  ....);
}

System.debug(String.join(debugLines,'\n');
```